# disable DatePicker when asp:Textbox disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp:Textbox`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" />
```

I added a datepicker using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Bind() {
 $('#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                dateformat: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
                minDate: '01/01/1947',
                maxDate: 0,
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '../../images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonText: ''
            }).mask('99/99/99?99', { placeholder: ''
            }).change(function () {
               dateComplete('<%=txtDate.ClientID %>', false, 'The Date cannot be a future date.', 'Date of Contact', $('#<%=hidSavedInteractionDate.ClientID %>').val(), $('#<%=lblNumber.ClientID %>').text(), '<%=txtDate.ClientID %>');
            });
}

</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load(Bind);
 </script>
```

I disabled the `asp:Texbox` in the behind code vb.net

```
txtDate.ReadOnly = True
txtDate.Enabled = False
```

I want the datepicker to be disabled a well. I tried this bellow, but it didn't work.

behind code vb.net:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "HideDate", "HideDate();", True)
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
HideDate() {

    if (disabled == true) {
        $("#txtMyTextBox").datepicker('disable');
    }
    else {
        $("#txtMyTextBox").datepicker('enable');
    }


}
 </script>
```

**On a side note**, I used this bellow and it did disable the datepicker, but it disables it whether the `asp:Textbox` is disabled or not. I want the datepicker to be disabled only when the `asp:Textbox` is disabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

        if (disabled == true) {
            $("#txtMyTextBox").datepicker('disable');
        }
        else {
            $("#txtMyTextBox").datepicker('enable');
        }


    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sunil's answer is helpful, but I did this with a more simple solution.

I added this to jQuery code where I initialized the datepicker:

```
 if ($('#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>').prop("disabled")) {
                $('#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>').datepicker("option", {disabled:true});
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your JavaScript to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   DisableDate() 
     { $('#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>').datepicker('disable'); }

   EnableDate() 
     {  $('#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>').datepicker('enable');  }
</script>
```

Then in the code behind, to disable the datepicker call:

```
txtDate.Enabled = False
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "DisableDate", "DisableDate();", True)
```

To enable the datepicker call:

```
txtDate.Enabled = True
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "EnableDate", "EnableDate();", True)
```